# Identify music from partial mp3 extract

Tags: search, music

I have an mp3 of ten seconds of popular music. I'd like to know what song it is from. There are no words to look up, just instruments (90s pop punk guitar).

Things I've tried:

- MusicBrainz Picard. No good for partial recordings. It matches the mp3 only with 10 second songs. I believe this song is much longer.
- http://audiotag.info/index.php no matches

Comment: Took me 7 failed capchtas to post this. Am I a robot?

Comment: I would give both [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/) & [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/) a try. They do pretty good hob identifying partial songs, from my experience, but you'll need to do install them on an Android/iOS/WP device.

Comment: You should also post your partial tune on [WatZatSong](http://watzatsong.com/en), you might get feedback from people who know it - it can be better than any software out there.